# Error with "pip install jira"

Tags: python, jira, python-jira

With the documentation at: https://pythonhosted.org/jira/#installation

It says:
The easiest (and best) way to install jira-python is through pip:

$ pip install jira
This will handle the client itself as well as the requirements.

When I try that I get the message:

```
pip install jira 

Collecting jira
  Using cached jira-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.9.0 (from jira)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.3.3 (from jira)
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests-toolbelt (from jira)
  Using cached requests_toolbelt-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.6.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jira)
Collecting tlslite>=0.4.4 (from jira)
  Using cached tlslite-0.4.9.tar.gz
Collecting oauthlib>=0.6.2 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.3.3->jira)
  Using cached oauthlib-1.0.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: six, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, requests-toolbelt, tlslite, jira
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 726, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 746, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/b4144dg915v87yrh1n1tv8r00000gn/T/pip-qp3nVi-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

I tried using sudo, and pip install --ignore-installed six

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: from what I can see there you have a pre-existing installation of six, so either run this on a virtualenv or do pip install six --upgrade and the run pip install jira

Comment: Thank you Aquiles.  When I run "pip install six --upgrade" I get a similar error message:  pip install six --upgrade
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/var/folders/0j/b4144dg915v87yrh1n1tv8r00000gn/T/pip-i7FQwx-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'

Comment: Try `pip install --ignore-installed six`

Answer (score 5):

Based on Viraptor and Aquiles suggestions:

This command works:

sudo pip install jira --ignore-installed

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165

Thanks for all the help.